# Fill combobox with values from table based on column value next to it VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I want to fill a combo box upon startup of userform with values in column A based on a value in Column C. 
i.e. my combobox options should list Items in column A if it's correponsing value in column C is "PINK"

Answer (score 2):

Some code of what you've already attempted is preferred. But you should try something like the following. Assume combobox1 is in UserForm1 :

```
Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

dim ws as worksheet
set ws = activesheet

rowsCount = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row

'loop over data in column A 
for i = 0 to rowsCount
    if ws.cells(i, 3).value = "PINK" then
        combobox1.AddItem(ws.cells(i, 1).value)
    end if
next i

end sub
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for! actually my code was just rotten and I tried pasting it on, but it's my first question on this forum and it needed it to be formatted a certain way which I didn't know how to do... :(

Comment: No problem. Just add 4 spaces at the beginning of a line to declare it as a block of code in your post. And don't forget to accept the answer too :). Cheers